# Python - Replace Dataframe in a Loop

Tags: dataframe, loops

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit' : ['Apple','Pear'],
              'Val' : [1,2],
              })

tmp2 = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit' : ['Apple','Pear'],
                  'Val2' : [3,3],
                  })

tomerge = pd.DataFrame({'Fruit' : ['Apple','Pear'],
                  'Colour' : ['Red','Green'],
                  })
```

I want to merge tmp and tmp2 with tomerge in a loop.

```
for i in [tmp,tmp2]:
    i =  pd.merge(i,tomerge,how='left', left_on='Fruit', right_on='Fruit')
```

How can I get tmp and tmp2 to be updated? tmp and tmp2 remain the same after running the loop.

The loop above merges tmp2 and tomerge and calls the dataframe "i" instead of tmp2 again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem you describe right here. I haven't found the best and optimized way however it should probably still help you out :) :

```
from minecraft import inventory as iv

tmp = iv.set(0 : ["golden_apple", 5])
tmp1 = iv.set(1 : ["ender_pearl", 16])

for i in [tmp, tmp1]:
   tmp_com = iv.combine_item_amount(i)

print(tmp_com)
```

With this setup it would return 21 "golden_apples", because "ender_pearls" can only be stacked up to 16. So the inventory system will automatically do the work for you.

Edit : However the inventory system is limited because of slots, you can only have 36 slots with armor 40. This may cause trouble, however if you never use more then 36-40 slots, everything should work.

Hope I could help :)